# How can I ask the right question so that I don't get banned?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently, I have been asking several questions about [SML/NJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML_of_New_Jersey). For some reason that I do not understand, I got banned (reached my question limit).

My Trials:

1. I read the entire forums and advice that was given, tried to apply some of them, but to no avail.
2. I asked some friends for a tailored advice by giving them my question and how should I enhance them and they gave some advice that I applied, but still to no avail.

I do respect the community and totally understand that asking a question is a privilege not a right and I will never try to bypass such limit because it was set for a reason. I am just trying to understand the reason so that I do not repeat the same mistake over and over.

These are my questions:

1. [Why is foldl signature is a pipeline instead of a tuple like type in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189187/why-is-foldl-signature-is-a-pipeline-instead-of-a-tuple-like-type-in-sml)
2. [What is the effect of adding a variable type binding in signature in SML on the Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228272/what-is-the-effect-of-adding-a-variable-type-binding-in-signature-in-sml-on-the)
3. [Why does "not" care about "List.exists" input in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212723/why-does-not-care-about-list-exists-input-in-sml)
4. [Forward Display from docker to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497045/forward-display-from-docker-to-host)
5. [the read function in my socket API does not work and lags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050183/the-read-function-in-my-socket-api-does-not-work-and-lags)

I have discovered that there is a bot that deletes questions automatically and some contributors linked them in comments.

1. [When to use circular recursion and when not to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69842645/when-to-use-circular-recursion-and-when-not-to-use-it)
2. [Failed to use SFTP over different ISP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581467/failed-to-use-sftp-over-different-isp)
3. [laptop screen not detected on Kubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401518/laptop-screen-not-detected-on-kubuntu)
4. [is there a solution for using more than 3 keys for shortcuts on Ubuntu with KDE installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946126/is-there-a-solution-for-using-more-than-3-keys-for-shortcuts-on-ubuntu-with-kde)
5. [why doesn't the thread start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792901/why-doesnt-the-thread-start)

Comment: How many deleted questions do you have?

Comment: @talonmies none, never deleted a question.

Comment: Huh, then that's weird. I don't remember there's a question limit for new users. Your question doesn't have any downvotes, so having a question ban is weird. Anyway, I think that a moderator could check for you soon.

Comment: Well the OP is right, they have never deleted a question; though they do have questions that have been deleted. The problem here is that none of your questions have a positive score, and hence why you're likely being limited. Though I suspect you also have some more deleted questions that have been downvoted.

Comment: You also have 5 deleted questions with scores <= 0 that are contributing to your [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/69842645) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/61581467) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/59401518) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/58946126) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/58792901)

Comment: @CodyGray
Seriously? xD? It is impossible for me to remember these things!, these were my first days in programming and interacting with linux without having a mentor. Now i remember why i did delete them, because they were closed and not answered, thus, I though that they were asking me to delete it :D.

Totally my problem but did not ever knew that a mistake done 2 1/4 years back can effect me now.

So what should I do cuz i seriously do not know what to do :)

Comment: @OmarShawky Closed questions with no answers eventually get automatically deleted by the Roomba bot. The questions listed by Cody in the comment above are such questions.

Comment: @Lundin I tried searching for those questions but did not find any useful guide into how to grab those deleted question, I still do not know what to do, should i answer my own questions?

Comment: @OmarShawky I don't think anything can be done about the deleted ones though they do contribute to the ban. Focus on those questions (and answers) which are still visible and try to polish them into shape or improve them in general.

Comment: Providing feedback is not mandatory. Users are allowed to vote on content without providing an explanation. Please don't ask users to do that, and definitely don't do that in the body of the question. Users will provide feedback if they want to.

Comment: Probably the reason your question here on meta has been downvoted is because the title *"How can I ask the right question so that I don't get banned?"* is covered pretty extensively in the help pages, e.g. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and although you mentioned reading "the entire forums" (?) for advice, you didn't say what specifically about that advice you were not able to understand or apply. The first five of your examples are questions which weren't closed/deleted anyway (except one closed as a duplicate, which doesn't necessarily mean the question is of ...

Comment: ... low quality). Of the other five, one is opinion-based *and you said in the question that you knew it was opinion-based but you asked it here anyway*, three are blatantly off-topic (not about programming), and the last one was closed a duplicate (again, not necessarily an indicator of quality). So it is really hard to see why, specifically, you are unsure what caused these questions to be deleted, and therefore it's hard to see what kind of answer you are expecting here on meta. For the record, I am not one of the downvoters, but that probably explains why this question was downvoted.

Comment: @kaya3 thank you, but in fact, my question is "what of these advice did i apply wrong in the questions that i mentioned" because i applied them and they make sense to me and even after applying them i am still banned, which means simply that i might understood one thing or more wrong, that is what i am asking people to clarify for me.

Comment: @kaya3 regarding the opinion based, i mentioned that it is opinion based and i mentioned that i did not know anywhere else to ask this question, the person closed the question did not even care to clarify where to ask it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That doesn't change the fact that you knew that question wasn't suitable when you posted it. There isn't an exception for allowing unsuitable questions just because the person asking doesn't know where else to ask them. The fact remains that you are asking here on meta what you should do to avoid your questions being deleted, yet one of your examples is a question where you apparently knew it was a bad question before you posted it. So effectively you're asking us to tell you something you already know.

Comment: @kaya3 You are right, i was just hopeless, thank you tho :)

Comment: @OmarShawky *the person closed the question did not even care to clarify where to ask it* What do you think obligates a volunteer on **this** site to research what **other** site might be suitable for answering your question?

Comment: @beaker how is this relevant? I am saying that all I needed was couple of words, do couple of words count as a favor or as an obligation? Sure i understand as I said in my question that any answer is an act of kindness but it seems that some people only cares about rating.

Answer (score 5):

I must say, congratulations on your attitude towards this. Usually these kind of meta posts are a little more... heated. Accusatory.

I want to respond to one statement you made though.

> for some reason that I do not understand

The comments are already trying to make that problem go away by providing you the information that makes up your ban. Downvoted posts, deleted posts. Contrary to what people like to believe, deleted posts actually keep counting. But the deeper problem here is that you were not even aware that you had deleted questions, right? To be honest that is not entirely your fault; deleted content is only visible in your user CP for a few months. It is a questionable design decision at best to be honest since they do not stop being a thorn in your side. BUT! That system limitation should not lead to a problem of you not knowing you had deleted content.

Because, yes, the system does warn you that you are on a downward spiral and a question ban is imminent. Allegedly because I wish someone would screenshot the actual message, it feels so academic to have to speak about that warning without ever actually having seen it. How can it happen that you miss it? I am going to have to be a little preachy about that; people who miss the signals tend to use the site a little too isolated; they're just here to ask questions when they please or perhaps they quickly jump in and out from Google when they're looking for an answer. And then they're gone again.

Effectively people don't "groom" enough. Your biggest tool for that is your user control panel (user CP for short). It should be checked periodically because there you can see comments you made and you might want to check if some of them maybe are in need of pruning, or a reaction needs to be posted. You can check your questions and answers to see how they are doing score-wise (or perhaps... notice that something you posted has been closed or even deleted...). If you cast flags, you can see if they are getting accepted or declined. Those sort of things. If you do that, you will notice things happening and can intervene before it can cascade into something that is hard to rebound from. Your biggest surprise should be that a question is downvoted or got deleted, not that you are question banned which is several stages later.

I can remember my first self-reflection moment; I had been casting flags which were declined a little too often. How did I notice this was happening? Because I checked my user CP to see what my flagging outcomes were doing. If I hadn't shown an interest, I wouldn't have known something was up.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118) shows what the warnings looked like back in 2014. I assume this has not changed too much. Importantly, it does *not* require looking at the user profile (which is the more typical term than "control panel"). Another example of the warning message is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD3YX.png).

Comment: @CodyGray if I well remember from few month ago, I can confirm that it's the same today

Comment: @CodyGray i have never seen this while posting.... AT ALL I SWEAR, nothing, nadda :D.

Comment: @OmarShawky Yes, that warning was not showing up for a very long time https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363728 It's been fixed now, but it's certainly possible that you weren't shown that message when it should have been.

Comment: Hmm so kind of the police stopping you, handing you a speeding ticket and then only afterwards put up a physical speed limit sign?

Comment: I am not sure where is the CP, but if you meant the inbox, i do check it regularly and i actually receive mail in case i did not check it for 3 hours.